# How To Implement the Show Password option in WiX Toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer, build-tools

I am currently implementing setup UI in WiX toolset to get the input password from the user. It contains Password and Confirm Password option I want to implement the Show Password check box. If it is checked the Password should be visible otherwise masked.

When I searched online for the solution, I saw WiX uses Windows Installer which doesn't support dynamic modification of controls.  Need to use workaround.

Workaround tried.

```
<Control Id="PasswordEdit" Type="Edit" X="120" Y="200" Width="220" Height="18" Property="USERPASSWORD" Password="yes">
  <Condition Action="hide">SHOWPASSWORD = "1"</Condition>
  <Condition Action="show">SHOWPASSWORD != "1"</Condition>
</Control>

<Control Id="PasswordEditPlain" Type="Edit" X="120" Y="200" Width="220" Height="18" Property="USERPASSWORD">
  <Condition Action="hide">SHOWPASSWORD != "1"</Condition>
  <Condition Action="show">SHOWPASSWORD = "1"</Condition>
</Control>

<Control Id="ShowPasswordCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="120" Y="220" Width="56" Height="10" Property="SHOWPASSWORD" Text="Show Password" CheckBoxValue="1" />
```

The workaround I tried it is not working I tried few others also it is not working.

I need to know whether implementing Show Password to view the Password in setup screen is possible or another workaround is there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **!=** , use **<>**

as stated in https://www.firegiant.com/docs/wix/v3/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/

like
`<Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[SHOWPASSWORD <> "1"]]></Condition>`

Comment: I think I have tried using that also not working. And then Implemented the screen without Show Password option only :)

Comment: My bad I forgot that we need to escape characters in the XML. So we use CDATA, to escape some characters. I have updated the above code and tested it and it works flawlessly!